# Json update using Jq MAP

Tags: json, edit, jq

I am new to JQ and i figured this should get what i am looking for but it throws me error which unable to resolve.

```
cat aws_test_query_history_pipeline.json |  jq '.parameters[] | map(if 
.id == "clusterName"
then . + {"id"="changed"}
else .
end
)' >> test_krish.json
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting '}' (Unix shell 
quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 2:
then . + {"id"="changed"}              
jq: 1 compile error
```

I know i am missing something silly please let me know what am i missing.

Update to this question as i was missing some info on it.

Sorry about that. here is my sample

```
 {
"objects": [
{
  "connectionString": "jdbc:mysql:
  1.rds.amazonaws.com",
  "*password": "",
  "name": "Insights",
  "id": "DataNodeId_XAL9t",
  "type": "MySqlDataNode",
  "table": "stas",
  "username": "porta"
  },
  {
  "dependsOn": { 
  .......
 ]
 "parameters": [
 {
  "id": "clusterName",
  "description": "Which region Cluster name to use",
  "type": "String",
  "default": ""
  },
 {
  "id": "password",
  "description": "Password to use",
  "type": "String",
  "default": ""
 }
 ]
 }
```

The above is on a file.json when i run this command it just gets me parameter array changed as mentioned on the command but i would also need the remaining json file untouched

```
cat test.json | jq '.parameters | if .id == "clusterName" then .id = 
"changed" elif .id == "password" then .id = "passchange" else . end' > 
test_krish.json
```

The above command is just giving me

```
 {
"id": "changed",
"description": "Which region Cluster name to use",
"type": "String",
"default": ""
}
{
"id": "passchange",
"description": "Password to use",
"type": "String",
"default": ""
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message indicates, `{"id"="changed"}` is wrong.  Perhaps you meant:

```
{"id":"changed"}
```

If you are indeed simply trying to change `.id`, you could write:

```
if .id == "clusterName" then .id = "changed" else . end
```

Btw, in future, it would be good if you followed the guidelines at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

#### Answer to Revised Question

```
(.parameters[].id |= if . == "clusterName" then "changed" else . end)
```

Comment: Thanks this helped but in my JSON i have two array and when i run the query at aws_test_query_history_pipeline.json | jq .parameters[] | if .id == "clusterName" then .id = "changed" else . end' > test_krish.json it dosent include the objects[] array on the output how could i get that included in the output file

Comment: As I said, you should follow the mcve guidelines.  In particular, you should include a representative sample of your input.

Comment: Thanks much for your response